# How to solve class/driver and know what will be the output

Tags: java, arrays

I am given an example of driver/class, and before attempting to find the answer on Java, I am suppose to predict what the output would be (by hand). However, I am having trouble about where to start like how do you know which variable is associated with what, and is there a certain order to follow (ie. which method in the class is followed first?). Is it possible if you can walk me through them?

```
public class Q3_Array_3E {
    public Q3_Array_3E() {
        int[][] a = create(6);
        int i = a.length - 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    int[][] create(int n) {
        int[][] a = new int[n][];
        a[1] = new int[3];
        a[1][1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = new int[i + 2];
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                a[i][j] = a[i - 1][j - 1] + a[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
// Driver (below)

public class Driver3E {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Q3_Array_3E();
    }
}
```

The solution is suppose to be 1 4 6 4 1

Answer (score 0):

Entry point of the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

First thing that happens - instance of `Q3_Array_3E` class creation:

```
new Q3_Array_3E();
```

When you call `new` you call class constructor:

```
 public Q3_Array_3E() {
        int[][] a = create(6);
        ...
 }
```

First line of constructor calls `create` method:

```
int[][] create(int n) {
    ...
}
```

What your program does:

1) Creates two dimension array and fills it with numbers

```
null
0 1 0
0 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 0
0 1 3 3 1 0
0 1 4 6 4 1 0
```

2) Iterates through this array last element and prints elements from 1 to 5

```
0 1 4 6 4 1 0 -> 1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: Hi can you give me an example what is happening in the output (where it says Creates two dimension array and fills it with numbers). What is confusing me is int[][] a = new int[n][]; and the a[1] = new int[3]; like show me how to approach 0 1 0 after null

Comment: When i did the for loop when i=2, length is 6, the a[2] = new int[4], so from there it's saying that at array a[2] it will have length of 4 values. So inside the next for loop I get a[2][1] = a[1][0] + a[1][1]. how do you get a[1][0] ? Also why is a[0] null?